# Temporarily disable QCompleter?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5, qlineedit, qcompleter

I have a `QLineEdit` plus a `QListView` widget,

1. When then `QListView` is visible, the completer should be disabled.
2. Otherwise the completer is enabled.

But it appears like there's no **enable/disable** interface for `QCompleter`. What should I do then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the completer from the `QLineEdit` will effectively disable it, you can later set it back again to enable it. To remove it, call `QLineEdit::setCompleter(QCompleter*)` with a null pointer. Use the same member function to set/restore it again later.